# MySQL design for associated IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to programming so forgive my simple questions.

Basically, I have two different tables containing data related to one another. I'd like to create a new column called "id" which will associate rows in both tables so that I can appropriately display the data.

When a user takes an action, a row is inserted into both tables.

What kind of properties should "id" have? Primary key, auto-increment on both tables or one table? How do I ensure that the same ID is inserted into both rows, do I insert into table1 first, then grab that ID and insert into table2?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Describe the issue you're trying to solve with this dirty hack.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the two tables? If they are that closely related it may not be necessary to be in different tables to begin with.

Comment: If one occurrence of a row in one table corresponds to one and only one row in another table, combine the two tables instead. Save yourself the trouble.

Comment: Okay guys, I think I can merge portions of the tables into each other. That should save me the trouble of creating IDs, for now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat difficult to answer your question without knowing what the two tables contain, but I suggest you read about [database normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html).

Regardless of how many tables you decide to have, each table should have an id column of some sort. Having a way to uniquely refer to a single row makes life a lot easier down the road when you need to make changes to the data. Auto-increment saves you from having to come up with your own unique primary key values.